# How to determine probability function for the given problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Joe randomly arranges $12$ glasses in a row: $6$ glasses of wine, $4$ glasses of whisky and $2$ glasses of vodka.
Find the distribution of the number of glasses *between* the $2$ glasses of vodka.

Let us firstly determine the position of the $2$ glasses of vodka out of the row. the number of options is $\dfrac{12!}{2!10!}=66$.
If we let $k$ be the number of glasses between the $2$ glasses of vodka, then I understand if $k=10$, then $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\dfrac{1}{66}$ because there is only one option for this occurrence.
How do I come up with a general formula to determine the value of the numerator for all possible values of $k$?

Comment: Hint: Think of blocks.

Comment: @trueblueanil Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Suppose there are $3$ bottles between the vodka bottles. (we categorize only as vodka and others (X)

Make a block of bottles $\boxed{V X X X V}$
Seven others $(X's)$ will be outside the block.

You should be able to determine
the number of permutations for the "$3$ case",
and then generalize for $k$

**PS:**
Since you started with permutations, I have written permutations, but it would be simpler to deal with it as *combinations*